# Error Deploying code to heroku when having Helpers folder required in composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, heroku

I'm new to heroku and I was trying to deploy my web app (working on local environment) to heroku. I followed documentation till step: `git push heroku master`. After heroku installs vendors, when it generating optimized autoload files, It show an Exception:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
remote:        Stack trace:
remote:        #0 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/tmp/bu...', '/tmp/build_c8be...', 66, Array)
remote:        #1 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
remote:        #2 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c('42ab15150aa748b...', '/tmp/build_c8be...')
remote:        #3 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c::getLoader()
remote:        #4 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/tmp/build_c8be...')
remote:        # in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
remote:
remote:        Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
remote:        Stack trace:
remote:        #0 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/tmp/bu...', '/tmp/build_c8be...', 66, Array)
remote:        #1 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
remote:        #2 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c('42ab15150aa748b...', '/tmp/build_c8be...')
remote:        #3 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c::getLoader()
remote:        #4 /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/tmp/build_c8be...')
remote:        # in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
remote:        PHP Fatal error:  composerRequire52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c(): Failed opening required '/tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/functions.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
remote:
remote:        Fatal error: composerRequire52f94ddc173261f270a6e983eeb90c6c(): Failed opening required '/tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/../../App/Helpers/functions.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /tmp/build_c8be5dba02b1fb54b907b9b78ea87415/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to young-oasis-37306.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/young-oasis-37306.git
```

Follow what it said, I think the problem is composer can't find App/Helpers folder, which is defined at composer.json:

```
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files" :[
            "App/Helpers/functions.php"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

However, because this works on local composer so I really don't know how to deal with it. Can you help me please?

Heroku chose platform packages for me, I will write it here, just in case.

- php (7.3.4)
- ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
- apache (2.4.39)
- nginx (1.14.2)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's complaining because it can't find a file in the path 'App/Helpers/functions.php' which doesn't exist really.

Try changing your files to the actual file path. I guess it would look something like this:

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files" :[
        "app/Helpers/functions.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Sadly, I tried to change composer.json to "./app/Helpers/functions.php" and "app/Helpers/functions.php" but none works. Can I get your email? I will send you the code I used and see if you can figure out what is its problem.

Comment: message me privately here, then I'll send you! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1489237/magus

Comment: hi @Magus. Could you guy share solution to resolve this issue? I also have the same issue above. Thanks in advance

Comment: hi @huyleuit just updated the solution, the files section must include the path relative to the project root. It should reflect the directory naming structure, not the class names.

Comment: @Magus Could you be more specific? I already change the file path to this format "files": ["app/Components/Function.php", "app/Helpers/Helper.php"] but still facing the error when deploying to Heroku

Comment: that should've worked... I wish I could help more, but it's really hard without access to the code. Check if composer dump-autoload -o works on your machine.